# Session not getting the variable prints long string

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have this session class

```
class Session 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            $this->initSession();
        }
    }

    public function setSessionId()
    {
        $_SESSION['Id'] = session_id();
    }

    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $_SESSION['Id'];
    }


     public function initSession()
    {
        session_start();
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $this->setSessionId();
    }


    public function isLogged(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['Id'])){
            return true;
        }else{
           $this->deleteSession();
           return false;
       }
   }
```

In my login.php I pass the id to my session but

```
$results['Id'] = session_id();
```

when I got to index.php and echo the Id it echos a long string not the current user Id

```
$session = new Session();
$id = $session->getSessionId();

echo $id;
```

Please help me how do I pass the variable!I have tried a lot but I seem to be stuck here!Would really appreciate some help

Comment: Do you have session_start() within your code?

Comment: yes I do  @Adam...

Comment: @Adam It's in `initSession()`, which is called by the `Session` constructor.

Comment: What content is $id outputting?

Comment: `4j28389lmerhton7agc47v5bj8` instead of 1 @Adam

Comment: You have `$_SESSION['Id'] = session_id();`. The session ID is a long string, not the user ID.

Comment: @Barmar how can I pass by $result array?

Comment: The session ID is not the same thing as the user ID you have stored in your database. They're two completely different things.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, beat me to it.

Comment: @Barmar how can I solve this

Comment: When the user logs in, put the user ID into another session variable, and use that.

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;`

Comment: in my login page how do I pass it to the session class?& how do I echo it @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add additional methods to your class:

```
public function setUserId($userid) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
}

public function getUserId() {
    return isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : null;
}
```

Then your login page should call `$session->setUserId()` after the user logs in, passing the ID from the database.